# menu wordpress con javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, menú, wordpress-theme

tengo un menu al hacer hover sobre el menu aparece un contenedor con cada enlace del submenu el problema es que quiero ocultar ese submenu y solo aparezca cuando paso el mouse. Lo estoy haciendo pero solo melo hace una vez y ya para que aparezca de nuevo me toca refrescar la pagina lo quiero hacer con un hover  y con un mouseleave de jquery pero no da lo desaparece una vez y ya no vuelve aprecer... mi codigo es

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $("li.menu-item").hover(function(){    //$("li.menu-item").hover(function(){
    $( this ).find(" > .sub-menu");         //$( this ).find(" > .sub-menu").show();
    let element = $(this)[0].lastElementChild;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = element.innerHTML;
     }), $("#demo").mouseleave(function() {
      $("#demo").hide();   
      });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Has ocultado el `$('#demo')` al sacar el ratón de encima, por lo tanto no vuelve a estar visible hasta que recargas la página.

Debes mostrarlo con `$("#demo").show()` dentro del `hover`.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $("li.menu-item").hover(function () {    //$("li.menu-item").hover(function(){
        $(this).find(" > .sub-menu");         //$( this ).find(" > .sub-menu").show();
        let element = $(this)[0].lastElementChild;
        document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = element.innerHTML;

        $("#demo").show();
    });

    $("#demo").mouseleave(function () {
        $("#demo").hide();
    });

});
```

Comment: uiiiiiiii que calidad muchas gracias ya me estaba dando dolor de cabezaaaa funciona perfectamente asi lo queria...